# Is it possible to have undefined as a key when foreaching over a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have been doing a code review and I see code like this:

```
var a = { ... }; // in reality, an actual object filled with key-value pairs
for (var key in a) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(key)) { // does this ever fail?
        do.stuff();
    }
}
```

My question is whether `key` can ever be undefined (or evaluated to `true` per `angular.isUndefined`). It seems unlikely, as when I try to do the following:

```
var a = { undefined: 'hello' }
```

It turns out that `undefined` is actually a `String`.

Comment: `undefined` isn't a string, but object literal syntax converts any key tokens to strings before inserting them into the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is whether `key` can ever be `undefined`

No. All keys (property names) of an object are converted to strings.

Comment: If this were a Map, the answer would be different.
It's not a Map.
Felix is 100% correct.